# Regex not matching patern

Tags: regex

I want to match a blood group letter and number `A+` from the string `A positive (A+)`.

I have this pattern, `(\([a-zA-Z]+(\+|-)\))\w+` but it doesn't work. I'll be glad if one can point out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What do you want the trailing `\w+` in your regex to accomplish? Your test string doesn't have anything after the trailing right parenthesis. With a quick test, if I remove the `\w+` from your regex, it matches the test string.

Comment: I might also posit that `\(([aboABO]+[+-])\)` better matches your use case. The changes are: 1. moving the parentheses out of the match (so you get `A+` instead of `(A+)` 2. changing all letters (i.e. `A-Z`) to just those that are valid antigen indicators (i.e. `ABO`) 3. removed grouping from the Rh factor and replaced it with a character class (i.e. `[+-]`).

Comment: Your regex pattern is working. Just remove `\w+`, it's not required.
regex = `/(\([a-zA-Z]+(\+|-)\))/gm`.

Input:   `"(A+)Hello world next blood(B-) B Negative next (AB-)ABNegative".match(/(\([a-z]+(\+|-)\))/gmi)`

Output: `['(A+)', '(B-)', '(AB-)']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your regular expression is not working, is because you specify that the pattern **must match** 1 or more instances of any word character `\w+`, **after the parenthesis ends** `(AB-)triestomatchthis`. Given that your string does not contain any characters after that, the pattern is not satisfied. Your current pattern matches the blood type and polarity in parentheses, *only if it is followed by word characters*:

- (A+)loremipsum
- (B-)willOnlyMatchThis

But will not match:

- (A+)
- (B-)

Therefore the solution must remove the problematic token matching. Two possible solutions and their rationale are provided below:

1. `(\(\w+\+?\-?\))`.

You will note that the logical or `|` was not used to match the polarity of the number. Instead we implemented two quantifiers `?` to avoid an unnecessary capture group.

Alternatively if you anticipate strings with parentheses that will not be relevant, such as:

- "A positive (but double check with the lab) (A+)"

a modification of your original attempt works best:
`(\([a-zA-Z]+\+?\-?\))`.

Both solutions were tested for all permutations of blood type and polarity.

**Bonus**: if you wish to maintain the capture group of the blood polarity, use `(\([a-zA-Z]+(\+|-)\))`.